# Cascade-none in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a project with entity framework 6, and I have some problems with the mapping issue, I leave you a sample of a code

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Descripcion;
    }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class MapPreciosProveedor : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductPrice>
{
    public MapPreciosProveedor()
    {
        this.ToTable("Inventory_prices", "dbo");
        this.HasKey<Guid>(s => s.Id);
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        this.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(e => e.ProductId)
            .HasColumnName("productId")
            .IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired<Product>(s => s.Product)
           .WithMany(g => g.ProductPrices)
           .HasForeignKey<Guid>(s => s.ProductId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

My problem is in the ProductPrice class, when saving I use a generic repository, and I take advantage of the addOrUpdate method of the migration class, and I need for no reason to cascade the Product class, I come from the nhibernate world, where that is solved by map with cascade-none

```
<many-to-one class = "Product" column = "productId" cascade = "none" />
```

but I can't find something similar in entity-framework, and I think my requirement is a common thing, and I imagine that EF6 must have some parametrization to solve this, or I'm not understanding something

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe you should describe what you want without referring to NHibernate and show your current code and describe how it apparently does something you're trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't know if the translation is not good, since I write in Spanish, but I put the example code and explained that I want to avoid cascading the Product navigation property, and I show how I did it in nhibernate, and the same I want to do EF6.

Comment: What is "cascading the Product navigation"? If you don't want it to cascade why do you have `.WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`?

Comment: When copying and pasting I forgot to remove WillCascadeOnDelete (true).
WillCascadeOnDelete () either true or false, it is only taken into account when deleting a record, it does not alter anything when adding or modifying, at least that's how it works for me

Comment: I've been reading a lot about it today, and apparently ef6 still has limitations compared to nhibernate, and from my understanding it is not possible to exclude objects from cascading. Or maybe I'm wrong that's why I ask

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by cascading. Again show the code, the *working* code, not just this *defining* code and tell where it doesn't work as you want.